# How to create platforms from my tile platforms in Phaser 3 using matter physics?

Tags: collision-detection, phaser-framework, tiled, matter.js

I am using Tiled to create my levels in Phaser 3. I have my level, and the platforms load in fine, however, my player goes right through them. How do I add matter bodies to *all* of my platforms that are loaded?

Code for my platforms:

```
        //Create tilemap
        const map = this.make.tilemap({key: 'map'});
        //Create tileset
        const tileset = map.addTilesetImage('Assets_City', 'tiles');
        const platforms = map.createStaticLayer('Ground', tileset, 0, 200);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use a tile to create the platforms?

Comment: It’s going to be the easiest method of designing the levels for my game. Doing this would allow me to design all my levels in tiled versus writing all the extra code

Comment: It's too vague to help you like this. Can you share your repo? Like that, I'll have the full context to work with & help you debug this

Comment: @ManuelAbascal https://github.com/roberto257/Phaser-Spiderman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line **`const platforms = map.createDynamicLayer('Ground', tileset, 0, 0);`**, add the following line:

```
platforms.setCollisionBetween(1, 50);
```

For your reference:

```
//Create tilemap
const map = this.make.tilemap({key: 'map'});
//Create tileset
const tileset = map.addTilesetImage('Assets_City', 'tiles');
const platforms = map.createDynamicLayer('Ground', tileset, 0, 0);
platforms.setCollisionBetween(1, 50);
```

**EDIT:**

OP couldn't make to run with my original solution because he removed these lines by error:

```
platforms.setCollisionByProperty({ collides: true});
this.matter.world.convertTilemapLayer(platforms);
```

Comment: What do the 1 and 50 values represent? All the tiles indexed 1-50?

Comment: Yes, I believe so: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap.html

Comment: I tried this, no errors appeared, however, my sprite disappeared. I'm not sure why, and I still need it in the game and I need it to make sure that it collides with the platforms. I pushed my current code to GitHub where this is occurring.

Comment: I'll take a look before going to sleep for sure

Comment: Have you tried to revert back to your last code before the last commit & add the code I gave you?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I had originally

Comment: Go to your root folder & add: `git checkout bd5c2237e4bfbd1c7f5e79fd9213b3baee78d066` change `index.html` script to `spiderman_game.js` file & add the code I gave you.

Comment: I’m confused...can I just use VS Codes git integration and git checkout from there?

Comment: I usually use the command line for github. But I edited my answer, I think you'll be able to get it if you follow my instruction even with your current code version.

Comment: Yes, the reason why you don't see the sprite is in your `index.html` you have you `testgame.js` linked instead of `spiderman_game.js`

Comment: I’ll fix that when I get home, don’t see why it wouldn’t work if it’s working on your end

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202499/room-for-robert-smith-and-manuel-abascal @ManuelAbascal could you check this message?

Comment: I added my problem that I couldn't solve to the chat. If you could be so kind as to take a look whenever you have a chance. No rush. Thanks

Comment: @RobertSmith could you create a question for the current issue you are having? Showcase all the details there & walk me through the code relevant to your issue.

Comment: Sure thing. Give me a minute. I will need to proper explain everything especially after all the changes I made last night!

Comment: Done. Hope that is clear enough. If not just comment below that post. Thanks